# square matrix pattern segmentaion fault and/or core dumped while taking large values

Tags: c

**My code works fine until input size of 500 but shows segmentation fault or/and core dumped for values greater than 500. It should be able to print the pattern for up to the input size of 1000. I am not able to understand the issue here please help me out here.**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        int number,m,n,p,q,r,i,N,P;
        double matrix[1000][1000];
    
        scanf("%d",&number);
        N = number;
        p=(2*number-1);
        P=p;
        q=((2*number)-2);
        r=0;
        
        matrix[q/2][q/2]=1;                                    //Center//
        
        i=0;
        
        while(i<(N-1))
        {
            for(r=0,p=(2*number-1);r<(q/2) && p>(q/2) ;r++,p--)
            {
                for(m=r;m<p;m++)      //Changing//                //left column//
                    for(n=r;n<=r;n++)//Constant//
                    {
                        matrix[m][n]= number;
                    }
                for(m=r;m<p;m++)      //Changing//                //Top row//
                    for(n=r;n<=r;n++)//Constant//
                    {
                        matrix[n][m]= number;
                    }
                for(m=r;m<p;m++)         //Changing//
                    for(n=(p-1);n<p;n++)//Constant//             //Right column//
                    {
                        matrix[m][n]= number;
                    }
                for(m=r;m<p;m++)         //Changing//
                    for(n=(p-1);n<p;n++)//Constant//            //Bottom row//
                    {
                        matrix[n][m]= number;
                    }
                number--;
            }
            i++;
        }
        
        for(m=0;m<P;m++)
        {
            for(n=0;n<P;n++)
            {
                printf("%0.0lf ",matrix[m][n]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You should really consider more useful variable names... m, n, p, q, r, i, N, P.  Also using n, N and p, P will likely work but is bad.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will keep in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing elements in your array up to twice your input number. When you enter 501 as an input, `p` will be 1001, your first `for` loop will try to write to `matrix[1000][0]`, which is out of bounds and will clobber the stack.